# TypeError: unsupported operand int and NoneType? Python

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

I'm writing a blackjack game for my class and I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the code at all, maybe I'm just staring at it too long but any help would be appreciated

```
def payout(betAmount):
    global option1
    if option1 == "1":
        betAmount*1.5
        return int(betAmount)
    elif option1 == "2":
        betAmount*=1.25
        return int(betAmount)
    elif option1 == "3":
        betAmount*=1.2
        return int(betAmount)
```

followed by this:

```
winning=payout(bet)
playerPool+=winning
```

sorry about that, the full code is:

```
import random, pickle

option1=None

def payoutRule():
    global option1
    pick=None
    while pick != "1" or "2" or "3":
        pick=input("""
What is the house payout you want to play with?

1- 3:2 (1.5X)
2- 5:4 (1.25X)
3- 6:5 (1.2X)\n
""")

        if pick == "1":
            option1=1
            break
        elif pick == "2":
            option1=2
            break
        elif pick == "3":
            option1=3
            break
        else:
            print("That is not a valid option!\n")

def payout(betAmount):
    global option1
    if option1 == "1":
        betAmount*1.5
        return int(betAmount)
    elif option1 == "2":
        betAmount*=1.25
        return int(betAmount)
    elif option1 == "3":
        betAmount*=1.2
        return int(betAmount)

def hitDeck():
    CARDS=(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11)

    drawCard=random.choice(CARDS)
    return drawCard

def aceCounter(hand):
    aces=hand.count(11)
    total=sum(hand)
    if total > 21 and aces > 0:
        while aces > 0 and total > 21:
            total-=10
            aces-=1
    return total


def main():
    print("\t\tWelcome to the Blackjack Table!")
    payoutRule()
    playerPool=int(250)

    while True:
        playerCard=[]
        dealerCard=[]

        playerBust=False
        dealerBust=False
        endGame=None
        bet=None

        playerCard.append(hitDeck())
        playerCard.append(hitDeck())
        print("You have", playerPool, "dollars to play with.")

        while True:
            bet=input("""
How much are you betting?
\t1- $5
\t2- $10
\t3- $25
""")
            if bet == "1":
                print("You put down $5 on the table.")
                bet=int(5)
                break
            elif bet == "2":
                print("You put down $10 on the table.")
                bet=int(10)
                break
            elif bet == "3":
                print("You put down $25 on the table.")
                bet=int(25)
                break
            else:
                print("That is not a valid choice!")

        while endGame != "1":
            totalPlayer=aceCounter(playerCard)
            print("You have", len(playerCard), "cards with a total value of", totalPlayer)
            if totalPlayer > 21:
                print("You are busted!")
                playerBust=True
                break
            elif totalPlayer == 21:
                print("You've got a blackjack!!!")
                break
            else:
                hit=input("""
Would you like to:
\t1- Hit
\t2- Stand
""")
                if "1" in hit:
                    playerCard.append(hitDeck())
                elif "2" in hit:
                    break
                else:
                    print("That is not a valid choice!")
        while True:
            dealerCard.append(hitDeck())
            dealerCard.append(hitDeck())
            while True:
                totalDealer=aceCounter(dealerCard)
                if totalDealer  <= 17:
                    dealerCard.append(hitDeck())
                else:
                    break
            print("The dealer has", len(dealerCard), "cards with a total value of", totalDealer)
            if totalDealer > 21:
                print("The dealer busted!")
                dealerBust=True
                if playerBust == False:
                    winning=payout(bet)
                    print("You won!")
                    print("You just won", winning, "dollars!")
                    playerPool+=winning
                elif playerBust == True:
                    print("You both busted but the house will still collect.")
                    print("You just lost", bet, "dollars...")
                    playerPool-=bet
            elif totalPlayer > totalDealer:
                if playerBust == False:
                    winning=payout(bet)
                    print("You won!")
                    print("You just won", winning, "dollars!")
                    playerPool+=winning
                if playerBust == True:
                    print("The dealer won!")
                    print("You just lost", bet, "dollars...")
                    playerPool-=bet
            elif totalPlayer == totalDealer:
                print("It's a draw, but the house still wins.")
                print("You just lost", bet, "dollars...")
                playerPool-=bet
            elif totalPlayer < totalDealer:
                print("The dealer won!")
                print("You just lost", bet, "dollars...")
                playerPool-=bet
            break

        if playerPool == 0:
            print("You don't have anymore money to play with!")
            break
        elif playerPool < 0:
            print("You owe the house", -playerPool, "dollars, time to work in the kitchen...")
            break
        print("You have", playerPool, "dollars in your pocket now.")
        playAgain=input("Press the Enter key to play again or 'q' to quit.\n")
        if "q" in playAgain.lower():
            break
```

The actual error is this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Software Design\Culminating project revised2.py", line 175, in main()

File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Software Design\Culminating project revised2.py", line 140, in main
    playerPool+=winning

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Show us the error message in full.  In fact, it'd probably be a good idea to also show us all the code in full.

Comment: Apart from forgetting a `=` for the `betAmount *= 1.5` line, your code should work just fine unless `bet` is `None`. or `option1` is not a string value you test for.

Comment: Show us `bet` and `option1` please.

Comment: `option1` is a terrible variable name, and you should probably pass it into this function as a second argument rather than use `global`

Comment: Remember, when you asking for help, give the people all the information they need to make it easy to solve the problem.  As it is, you haven't stated where the error occurs (the error message tells you this) and we have know idea how you created the `bet` variable so we don't know what type of object it is.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that after my post, you added *too much* information.  Please have a look at http://sscce.org/ to see what is the right amount of information to post when asking a coding question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `option1` in `payoutRules` you assign **integer** values.

When you check `option1` in `payout` you compare it against **strings**. It cannot match anything, and thus `payout` always returns `None`.

You could change your `payout` function to:

```
def payout(betAmount):
    return betAmount * (1.5, 1.25, 1.2)[option1]
```

Doing it this way you use `option1`, which is an integer to index into the `(1.5, 1.25, 1.2)` tuple to get the multiplier to multiply with `betAmount`. If `option1` is not an integer, you'll get an error right there.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I definitely overlooked that one, instead of changing the function I actually got rid of the quotation marks in my payout() function since it seem to work the same way. I guess I just needed another set of eyes to look at it

Answer (score 0):

Your function will return `None` if `option1` is neither `'1'` nor `'2'` nor `'3'`. In this case adding `winning` (which is the result of `payout`) to `playerPool` will fall.

Maybe you add a `print(option1)` as first line of your function, to see what it looks like.

You can refactor your function this way:

```
def payout(betAmount, option1):
    return int({'1': 1.5, '2': 1.24, '3': 1.2}[option1] * betAmount)
```

This way you get at least an key error, when the `option1` is not a valid option.